# iOS - missing Platform Libraries

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios7

First of all, I've never worked on iOS, so this may or may not be a stupid question, I don't know :)

I have an iOS App, and I need to run it.

In the 'Project Navigator' I have a folder/package called 'Reuse and Platform Libraries'. Inside, I have another four folders but 3 of them seem like missing.

I am not sure if this is the case. I've tried googling their name but without results so I assume they are not some open source libraries.

Can someone clear this up for me? Do I need to install some XCode packages?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: you have to download the reuse and platform libraries from Github and add to the framework or simply drag and drag the files in your project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you search the folder of the project for those files, sometimes when copying a project the paths get screwed up because they were set as absolute paths and not relative paths.

If you can't find the files, it's most likely that the library is a private one used by the previous developers, and usually kept out of the project folder so they probably forgot to send it along. I'd suggest simply asking them to send the files over :).

There is also a slight chance they are not needed to run the file, in which case, just deleting them from the sidebar should make the project run.

Comment: The files aren't there, and I've also tried to  compile the project without them, but there are imports pointing toward them. It seems like I need to send some emails :). Thanks for your answer.